Leaflet - Create circles with numbers in the center that will be proportional to the boundaries in which the addresses are located
I've placed a marker on the map for each address, but it's messy, and my goal is to create a circle for each city. Inside each circle, I want to display the number of addresses located in that city, and the size of the circle should depend on the number of addresses. In the .csv file, each address has separate fields for the city and country.
Any help is welcome, thank you in advance.

let map = L.map('map', {
      minZoom: 2,
      maxZoom: 9
});

map.setView([48.54272537231445, 16.105000228881836], 8);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);


  // Read markers data from data.csv
jQuery.get('addresses.csv', function(csvString) {
    // convert string to array of objects
    let data = Papa.parse(csvString, {header: true, dynamicTyping: true}).data;

    // For each row in data, create a marker and add it to the map
    for (let i in data) {
      let row = data[i];

      let marker = L.marker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {
        opacity: 1
      }).bindPopup(row.Title);
      
      marker.addTo(map);
    }

});

EDIT:
Leaflet.markercluster was all I needed to solve this. Everything is nicely explained here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#usage
// Read markers data from data.csv
jQuery.get('addresses.csv', function (csvString) {
  // convert string to array of objects
  let data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;

  let markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {

      let groupBounds = cluster.getBounds();
      // Calculate the cluster center
      let clusterCenter = groupBounds.getCenter();
      // Convert the coordinates of the cluster center to pixels
      let clusterCenterPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(clusterCenter);
      // Convert the coordinates of the upper right corner of the bounds to pixels
      let northeastPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(groupBounds.getNorthEast());
      // Calculate the distance between points in pixels
      let distanceInPx = clusterCenterPoint.distanceTo(northeastPoint);

      let html = '<div>' + cluster.getChildCount() + '</div>';
      return L.divIcon({
        html: html,
        className: 'mycluster',
        iconSize: L.point(distanceInPx, distanceInPx),
      });
    },
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
    showCoverageOnHover: true,
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
  });

  // For each row in data, create a marker and add it to the map
  for (let i in data) {
    let row = data[i];

    if (row.Latitude != null && row.Latitude != null) {
      let marker = L.marker(
        new L.LatLng(row.Latitude, row.Longitude),
        {}
      ).bindPopup(row.Latitude + " " + row.Longitude);
      markers.addLayer(marker);
    }
  }
  map.addLayer(markers);
});

});

.mycluster {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    background: rgba(39, 133, 245, 0.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: black;
}

Here is how it looks

"my goal is to create a circle for each city" ... And where is your coding attempt at this?

@GetSet I don't like the way I started it, and I want to see more different approaches to how this can be done.

Although you may not like your current code, by not showing it suggests that you  are not motivated. And if you havent put in the effort, why should anyone else?

Showing code that doesnt address the actual problem is not a replacement for a coding attempt that does address it. ... FYI https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

@GetSet because of people like you I avoid asking questions here..

Marko I'll take that as a compliment. Looking for others to code for you is not going to help you build better code in the long run.

you can try poitToLayer
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
radius: 15,
weight: 1,
opacity: 0.1,
fillOpacity: 0.02,
stroke: false,
interactive: true,
bubblingMouseEvents: false,
});
},

or you can use a cluster with L.markerClusterGroup, it will create a cluster so the number of cites can be found with it, and with its iconCreateFunction you can customize its look and feel

I knew there was a much simpler solution. Thank you so much @himanshu. I managed to solve it with L.markerClusterGroup, which was exactly what I was looking for.

@GetSet take a look at the solution, and I hope you'll understand how unnecessary your comments were. If you can't help someone, don't bother commenting. Luckily, there are people like himanshu to guide me in the right direction.

As it stands, you still dont show in your question how your "problem" was solved. Sure you show some new code but fail to explain how it solves the many points you originally posed as the problem.

@GetSet the Leaflet.markercluster which I linked above, solves everything I mentioned earlier that I need. I just need to add the addresses from the .csv file, as I demonstrated in another piece of code. I really don't know what's wrong with you, honestly, even a blind person can see how this works, what's there to explain. I think you're just a little lonely and looking for any triviality to argue with people to feel a bit more important in your boring life.

Marko, abusive language are not allowed on Stack Overflow. You mistook questions I asked in the faith of debugging as a personal attack and in fact you are now engaging in actual personal attacks. The fact remains is you do not explain how the leaflet cluster solved your problems and thus your question doesnt help the community. "Everything is nicely explained here" points to an offsite link. Your own summary on how it helped you should be either in your question, in comments, or an answer.
